# How to plot bar chart with sub groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I'm trying to plot a bar chart to compare the results of a different combination of data treatments. I use this code:

```
  ggplot(data, aes(x=Missing, y=Accuracy, fill=factor(CV, c("Yes", "No")))) + 
                geom_bar(position=position_dodge(width=0.9), stat="identity") + 
                facet_wrap(~CV) + 
                facet_grid(~ï..method) + 
                position=position_dodge(width=0.9), size=2.75) + 
                geom_text(aes(y=0.3, label=CV, fontface="bold"), color="white", position=position_dodge(width=0.9), angle=90, size=3) + 
                theme_bw() +
                theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position="bottom", 
                        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
                        axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_text(face="bold"), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), 
                        panel.background=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), panel.grid.major=element_blank())
```

I get this:

[image]

I have 4 categorical variables and one continuous and I just can plot 3 categorical and 1 continuous. I want to add another division like this:

[image]

How can I do it?

Here is my data:

```
method  CV  Data        Missing     Accuracy
LDA     No  Original    Listwise    0.957410585
LDA     No  Original    Imputed     0.432106324
LDA     No  PCA         Listwise    0.863334196
LDA     No  PCA         Imputed     0.372696571
LDA     Yes Original    Listwise    0.816206002
LDA     Yes Original    Imputed     0.327353166
LDA     Yes PCA         Listwise    0.168329058
LDA     Yes PCA         Imputed     0.728472703
QDA     No  Original    Listwise    0.211201431
QDA     No  Original    Imputed     0.440153873
QDA     No  PCA         Listwise    0.314060191
QDA     No  PCA         Imputed     0.032602724
QDA     Yes Original    Listwise    0.378060808
QDA     Yes Original    Imputed     0.336361881
QDA     Yes PCA         Listwise    0.782062367
QDA     Yes PCA         Imputed     0.626905883
RDA     No  Original    Listwise    0.554855147
RDA     No  Original    Imputed     0.285762134
RDA     No  PCA         Listwise    0.230458084
RDA     No  PCA         Imputed     0.016533415
RDA     Yes Original    Listwise    0.831917301
RDA     Yes Original    Imputed     0.529697757
RDA     Yes PCA         Listwise    0.798245777
RDA     Yes PCA         Imputed     0.921277472
```

Comment: Your `ggplot` code does not compile. Be sure code and data works for a [mcve]. And include all `library` lines in code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider extending the `facet_grid` formula with `+` for added variables such as `facet_wrap(~Data + method)`. Below assumes your cut-off code involved `geom_text` for `Accuracy` label. Play around with order for desired layout. With `switch="x"`, both set of facet labels were moved to bottom.

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x=Missing, y=Accuracy, fill=factor(CV, c("Yes", "No")))) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(width=0.9), stat="identity") + 
  facet_grid(~Data + method, switch="x") + 
  geom_text(aes(y=Accuracy, label=round(Accuracy, 4)),
            position=position_dodge(width=0.9), size=2.75) + 
  geom_text(aes(y=0.3, label=CV, fontface="bold"), color="white", 
            position=position_dodge(width=0.9), angle=90, size=3) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position="bottom", 
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_text(face="bold"), 
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), 
        panel.background=element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major=element_blank())
```

[image: Plot Output]

Even add `strip.background=element_blank()` item to your `theme()` to remove the gray background: